# Cache invalidation; refetch practices when nothing says the data has changed, but it might have?

Tags: caching, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, cache-invalidation

While learning about GraphQL and Apollo, I went through [this tutorial series](https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/tutorial-graphql-input-types-and-client-caching-f11fa0421cfd).

It shows how to create an application, that has:

- A channel list view (`/`)

  - Shows all channels
  - Allows to open up channel detail view
  - Allows to create new channel
- A channel detail view (ie. `/soccer`)

  - Shows messages added to channel
  - Allows user to add a new message

Apollo by default caches queries and that presents an issue:

1. open channel (`/soccer`), for the first time, data is not present in cache, query is executed and result stored in cache
2. go back to channel list view
3. open a different channel (`/baseball`)
4. other visitor adds a message for `/soccer`
5. go back to channel list view
6. open channel (`/soccer`), due to data being present in store - stale data gets loaded, because nothing says the data is stale and should be refetched

I cannot seem to find a reasonable way to tackle it. Not looking for code, just some good practices on how to handle it with GraphQL.

I tried changing [`fetchPolicy`](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/api-queries.html#graphql-config-options-fetchPolicy) to `cache-and-network`, but it doesn't ask for more data - same applies, nothing says the data is stale. `network` works, but that goes around cache - a viable solution when it fits the requirements, but I actually wan't some caching.

Possible options I have thought of:

- Separate queries: one for main channel details, one for messages. Set messages `fetchPolicy` to `network`. Viable option, but sends already available data around.
- Separate queries. Messages are being paginated. Upon loading determine if first load or not and [`fetchMore`](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/pagination.html#fetch-more).
- Utilize a GraphQL subscription that notifies about server side events, use that to determine if should refetch. Introduces loads of other nuances, for instance, how long should I listen to events for channel X if I have already left it.

I know it depends on the project, but what other options are out there, which are favored, why?